# C structure and file handling newb - struggling

Tags: c, file-io, struct, replace

I'm a C newb struggling with a homework C problem. It is required that i creat a simple program that writes a struture type to a file and then reads the file recovering the data inserted previously. I got these two parts working.

There is another funcionality that is required, that basically asks to replace a 'char' type in the strutures previously entered in the file with another value. The desired effect is that it has a initial '0' value that enables that item to be showed, and when replaced with another vaalue, it isn't showed anymore.

If anyone would be so kind to take a look at this to help me sort it out, I'd be really thankful.

BTW, I *have* read other questions in SO regarding these kind of topics, and they all followed a 'replace' the output file logic as far as I can tell. They used a buffer to hold the data and compare it sequentially and then output a new file with different content.

I'm trying to do something different, and what I found, didn't really help me at all.

If the answer is in one of these other questions, please be so kind as to point it out to me and explain it.

Here is the code I have produced so far, I added some comments to briefly explain parts of the code since the outputs are in portuguese. My difficulty is in the case 3 of the switch() :S

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char license_plate[6];
    char owner_name[80];
    char deleted;
}vehicle_t;

void read_register(vehicle_t *v){ // function to read a struture of the type vehicle_t
    char temp[8];
    printf("insert license plate: \n"); 
    scanf("%s", temp);
    memcpy(v->license_plate, temp, 6);
    printf("Insert owner name: \n");
    getchar(); 
    fgets(v->owner_name, 80, stdin); 
    v->deleted=0; // initializtion of 'deleted'
}

void print_register(vehicle_t *v){ // function to print a vehicle_t type
    printf("\nRegister details: \n");
    printf("License plate: ");
    fwrite(v->license_plate, sizeof(char), 6, stdout);
    printf("\nOwner: ");
    printf("%s", v->owner_name); 
    printf("\n");
}

void show_menu(){ //just a small interface to display several options in a menu

    vehicle_t reg;
    char temp_del[10];
    FILE *fp;

    int opt;

    system("clear");

    printf("make your option:\n 1. new register \n 2. see registers \n 3. delete registers \n 4. exit \n");

    scanf("%d", &opt);
    getchar();

    switch(opt){
        case 1: //option to insert in the file 'registos.txt' - OK
            system("clear");
            fp = fopen("registers.txt", "a+");

            read_register(&reg);


            fwrite(&reg, sizeof(vehicle_t), 1, fp);
            fclose(fp);
            show_menu();
        break;

        case 2: // function to read from 'registos.txt' - also OK
            system("clear");
            fp = fopen("registers.txt", "r");

            if(fp==NULL){ //no file test
                system("clear");
                printf("No file!\n");
                getchar();
                show_menu();
            }else{ // if 'deleted' is != 0 don't print it out
                while(fread(&reg, sizeof(vehicle_t), 1, fp)!=0){
                    if(reg.deleted==0){
                    print_register(&reg);

                    }
            }
                printf("Press enter!");
                fclose(fp);
                getchar();
                show_menu();
            }
        break;

        case 3: 
            system("clear");        
            printf("License plate to delete?:\n");
            scanf("%s", temp_del);

            fp = fopen("registers.txt", "r+");
            while(fread(&reg, sizeof(vehicle_t), 1, fp)!=0){
                              // my problem is here! i'm not getting the 'deleted' value replaced in the file from '0' to '1'. I'm trying to find it's position and then goback the size of the struture and replace with the value '1' at the end. what am i doing wrong?
                if(strcmp(reg.license_plate, temp_del)==0){
                    reg.apagado='1';
                    fseek(fp, -sizeof(vehicle_t), SEEK_CUR);
                    fwrite(&reg, sizeof(vehicle_t), 1, fp);
                    printf("Register deleted!\n");
                }
            fclose(fp);
            getchar();
            show_menu();
            }
        break;

    case 4:
            system("clear");
            return;
        break;

        default:
            printf("No such option, please wait 3 seconds.\n");
            system("sleep 3");
            show_menu();
        break;
    }
}   

int main(){

    show_menu();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what you are doing with replacing a char is not clear. To make the matters worse, you have named every identifier non-English language, which makes it hard to read the code.

Comment: alright, i got it working to delete, but another problem showed up...
it replaced the 'deleted' char in the struture previously placed in the file, but now it does not replace in other instances of the same structure in the same file... must be related to the while cycle for sure... any ideas?

btw, haven't changed anything but the strncmp suggestion of grand admiral... 

now it works, but only for the 1st instance of the structure in the txt file...

Comment: guess i spoke too soon... thats not the problem after all... i got the program to replace like i wanted too, but now when i try to do the same to another iteration of the structure in the txt file, nothing chagnges, but the first one has been changed as i desired though... should i push the cursor to the next iteration of the struture in the file at the end of the while cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check a couple of things:

1. Does the `strcmp` ever return 0? (set a breakpoint in the block after)
2. Check `temp_del` -- is it just `apagado`, or does it have extra characters (maybe `\n`)

Comment: 1. i tried to check for strcmp's return value, but it actually isn't entering the if statement... don't have a clue why... i think this way it should work...

2. temp_del supposedly shouldn't have \n because of its size. it can't store more than 6. tried changing the size of temp_del to 6: no success, though...

Comment: If the size of `temp_del` is 6, then it will only store 'apaga' because `temp_del[5]` will be '\0'.  Make sure you look at temp_del in the debugger (if you can't use a debugger, print it out!)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `strncmp(str1, str2, 6)` to avoid any end of line character problems.

Comment: tried it already... no sucess, does not enter the if... for some reason the reg.deleted and the temp_del 6 first caracters arent triggering the if... could it be the == operator?

Comment: I'll second RunHolt's comments then in that you should print out/look at the string contents.  Or maybe try just using numbers for the license plate to avoid any character capitalization problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the two values, `reg.license_plate`, and `temp_del` as hex to see *exactly* what they look like.

```
for (int i=0; i<6; ++i) {
    printf("reg.license_plate[%d]=%X  temp_del[%d]=%X\n", 
            i, reg.license_plate[i], i, temp_del[i]);
}
```

If the `if (strcmp(...)` is not being entered, then either the strcmp sees them as two different strings, or the `while(fread(&reg, sizeof(vehicle_t), 1, fp)!=0)` is failing

This is not as urgent or important as finding the bug, but because this is homework I'd recommend you modify your struct definition a little.

There are lots of numbers which set the size of things which woul be hard to chenge. Instructirs usually look for that sort of thing. The classic way of doing it is to have a few names which define sizes:

```
#define MAX_LICENSE_PLATE (6)
#define MAX_OWNER_NAME (80)
typedef struct {
    char license_plate[MAX_LICENSE_PLATE];
    char owner_name[MAX_OWNER_NAME];
    char deleted;
} vehicle_t;
```

If your compiler supports it, it is better to use

```
const int MAX_LICENSE_PLATE = 6;
const int MAX_OWNER_NAME = 80;
```

instead, but some C compilers won't let you define array sizes that way.

**Always* put a '\0' onto the end of strings when you memcpy() the value.
For example

```
void read_register(vehicle_t *v){ // function to read a struture of the type vehicle_t
    char temp[MAX_LICENSE_PLATE+2];
    printf("insert license plate: \n"); 
    scanf("%7s", temp);  // I should go check how to specify width at run-time
    memcpy(v->license_plate, temp, MAX_LICENSE_PLATE);
    v->license_plate[MAX_LICENSE_PLATE-1] = '\0';
    printf("Insert owner name: \n");
    getchar(); 
    fgets(v->owner_name, MAX_LICENSE_PLATE, stdin); 
    v->deleted=0; // initializtion of 'deleted'
}
```

**NOTE:** fgets keeps the newline character '\n'; so you should trim that off too.